# Querying a SQL table column that contains JSON and updating a value in that JSON based on a condition

Tags: sql-server, json, ssms-2012

This table has about 1.5 million rows. A particular column contains JSON. What I need to do is query that column for that JSON and then query for a particular boolean key/pair "FLAG" in that JSON. If that "FLAG" is `True`, I'll need to update another key/pair in that JSON to a `Null` value rather than the string that it currently is.

The tricksy part of this for me is that I have to query the JSON itself and run the check. But it's not like I can index the JSON like in other languages, it's effectively a string that I'm going to need to query via sql-regex. I'm also a bit confused as to how I will surgically update the second key/pair to a `null`.

```
 Json Start: 
 {
    "flag": true,
    "anotherKvP": "some string"
 }
 How I need the Json to be updated to: 
 {
    "flag": true
    "anotherKvP": null
 }
```

Comment: mysql or sql server? And can you provide some details?

Comment: @SeanLange - sorry, SQL Server. Corrected the tags. Added details.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up coming across a function called `STUFF ( character_expression , start , length , replaceWith_expression )` which allowed me to jam together a string within a string. That's the second part.

The first part, in my `FROM` clause, I selected the value's index I needed to split on using `PATINDEX ( '%pattern%' , expression )` to gather the starting index of the patterned position.

Lastly, the `WHERE` and `LIKE` was used to pattern match the query for the  `"flag": true`.